# SynEdit won't install in Delphi 10.1 Berlin Starter Update 1

Tags: delphi, access-violation, delphi-10.1-berlin, synedit

I'm trying to install SynEdit into my newly upgraded Delphi 10.1 Berlin Starter Update 1, but it won't work. Someone else also seem to be having this problem, but I do not know how to fix it. https://forums.embarcadero.com/thread.jspa?messageID=850362

Can someone help me please? I'm trying to use the GetIt Package Manager. I also tried installing it from the source which I downloaded from the Internet.

[image]

Comment: All I know is that it works in Delphi 10 Seattle for me.

Comment: What happens if you forget the Getit Manager and download and install SynEdit manually?

Comment: I had to use the manual install too (10.1 Berlin Architect). GetIt didn't work for me, in Berlin. It works fine in Seattle.

Comment: It worked before the update and on previous versions of Delphi. Installing it manually gives me an access violation error.

Comment: Is the one you're installing explicitly made for 10.1?

Comment: Well it worked before the update and it is within the GetIt Package Manager. So I would assume so.

Comment: Also, that thread which you link has a different error than you're having.

Comment: I downloaded the newest one available at that time. I downloaded it like 2 months ago.

Comment: I linked to that link because this person is also experiencing a problem with SynEdit after updating to the newest Delphi 10.1 Berlin.

Comment: "I downloaded it like 2 months ago" Well did you try downloading the latest one? Most likely the one from 2 months ago wasn't designed for 10.1 Update 1.

Comment: I'll try and download the latest one again tonight. Will be back when it's done.

Comment: According to this: https://github.com/TurboPack/SynEdit it was last updated 3 months ago and I downloaded it 2 months ago. So yes I do have the newest version still. It worked fine before the update. It gives me an access violation error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I was able to fix the problem myself after two days of struggling.

So what I did was I completely uninstalled Delphi 10.1 Berlin Update 1 from my computer and deleted all of the files I could find which the uninstaller didn't remove and then I also downloaded the SynEdit files again from https://github.com/SynEdit/SynEdit and then I went to the GetIt Package Manager and tried to install it from there, but it still gave me an access violation error. After this I tried installing it from the downloaded source and then it seemed to work.

So now it is fixed. Thanks.

I'm assuming that some files somewhere were left behind from the previous version of Delphi and this needed to be removed first.